# building a calculator with ocaml, no idea how to make sigma function

Tags: function, ocaml

I'm currently working on making a function that accepts self made type called exp and do arithmetic process (+-*/) and sigma. Current work status is as follows and I don't know how to proceed.

```
type exp = X
     | INT of int
     | ADD of exp * exp
     | SUB of exp * exp
     | MUL of exp * exp
     | DIV of exp * exp
     | SIGMA of exp * exp * exp

let rec calculator : exp -> int
= fun e -> match e with
| INT x -> x
| ADD (e1, e2) -> calculator e1 + calculator e2
| SUB (e1, e2) -> calculator e1 - calculator e2
| MUL (e1, e2) -> calculator e1 * calculator e2
| DIV (e1, e2) -> calculator e1 / calculator e2
| SIGMA (e1, e2, e3) -> let start = calculator e1 in 
                    let end = calculator e2 in
                    match start with
                    | x -> 
                    | _ -> expr2
```

for example, SIGMA (INT 1, INT 10, SUB(MUL(X,X), INT 1)) should produce result of 375.

Actually I'm referencing a book called 'OCaml from the very beginning' and the reference code is also not working (below) so I cannot proceed right now...

```
 type expr = 
 Num of int
|Add of expr * expr
|Subtract of expr * expr
|Multiply of expr * expr
|Divide of expr * expr

let rec evaluate e = 
    match e with
    | Num x -> x
    | Add (e, e') -> evaluate e + evaluate e'
    | Subtract (e, e') -> evaluate e - evaluate e'
    | Multiply (e, e') -> evaluate e * evaluate e'
    | Divide (e, e') -> evaluate e / evaluate e'
```

Comment: Sigma as in sum? I don't know anything about the language you're using, but I bet you could just summarize all the numbers using a loop.

Comment: You need to maintain some environment and variable bindings in it. I'm sure I have answered a similar question. So your `calculator` or `evaluate` needs an additional argument carrying the environment ... and your `expr` type probably need an additional case `Var of string`  for variables, or `VarX` if you have only one variable `x`

Comment: The `| x ->` clause doesn't have an expression, you use `end` as a variable but it is a keyword. Finally, you might consider thinking about what happens when the result of calculating the dividend is zero.

Comment: @gsg, you probably meant `| X ->` as the missing pattern.

Comment: My guess is that you don't necessarily need a full environment for named variable bindings, but perhaps just a stack to keep track of the `X` variable for embedded sigmas?

Comment: @didierc: I copied a problematic fragment from the OPs source code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution :

```
type exp = 
  | VAR of string
  | INT of int
  | ADD of exp * exp
  | SUB of exp * exp
  | MUL of exp * exp
  | DIV of exp * exp
  | SIGMA of exp * exp * exp * exp

module SMap = Map.Make (String)

let rec aux_sigma var b env e =
  let rec aux env acc =
    let v = SMap.find var env in
    if v > b then acc
    else 
      let res = calculator env e in
      aux (SMap.add var (v + 1) env) (acc + res)
  in aux env 0

and calculator env = function
  | VAR x -> SMap.find x env
  | INT x -> x
  | ADD (e1, e2) -> calculator env e1 + calculator env e2
  | SUB (e1, e2) -> calculator env e1 - calculator env e2
  | MUL (e1, e2) -> calculator env e1 * calculator env e2
  | DIV (e1, e2) -> calculator env e1 / calculator env e2
  | SIGMA (var, e1, e2, e3) -> 
    match var with
    | VAR x ->
      let init = calculator env e1 in 
      let bound = calculator env e2 in
      aux_sigma x bound (SMap.add x init env) e3
    | _ -> assert false

let e1 = SIGMA (VAR "X", INT 1, INT 10, SUB(MUL(VAR "X", VAR "X"), INT 1))

let () = Printf.printf "%d\n" (calculator SMap.empty e1)
```

I changed your `X` constructor to a `VAR of string` one because you may need multiple variables in your sigmas and added the variable that is used as the control variable. Another thing I did is that your initial value should be lower than your bound or the program will run forever.

The idea behind the solution is like Basile said, you just maintain an environment that links each variable to its associated value and the `aux_sigma` function just runs `calculator` on the expression incrementing the variable that was used in `SIGMA` and, then, changing its binding in the map.